# Ignite cache hash

Tags: java, ignite

For develop/debug purpose I would like to have an easy way to detect Ignite cache differences on multiple (actually two) environments running the same application. Just a fact of difference, there are already developed tools to dump a cache for investigation. Cache mode is replicated.

I'm thinking about computing hash of a cache and then just comparing two Strings. Either on demand or by schedule. Request comes from client node.

What is the best way to archive that?
Does Ignite provide suitable tool out of the box (for example, `IgniteCache.hashCode()` could do it)? 
Is it a good idea to run a job on cluster to evaluate computation on server node and avoid data transfer? If so, how to run job only on single server node that is primary for cache?

Cache is up to 1 million "small" entries. Computation would be requested not frequently and only on develop environments.

UPD. Multiple environments means separate Ignite clusters, but connected to the same data source and thus expected to store the same data.

Comment: As far as I know `REPLICATED` cache can't have any backups, it doesn't need them, it's already on the every node of a cluster. To be honest I haven't caught your idea at all. You said you have a dumping utility, why won't you use it?

Comment: @VladimirPligin , dumping entire cache by existing utility requires all data to be transfered from server node to client node and then via http to initial client. I would like to perform it only if necessary. Also, solution with hash allows to log it and keep history.

Comment: @VladimirPligin . And finally, obtaining somehow hash on client node easily allows to add it on existing diagnosting web ui. Thanks for remark on replicated mode backups, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

If you start your cache in `REPLICATED` mode then Ignite would do the work for you.
Using IgniteCache.hashCode() is not recommended because it was not designed for that purpose.

more info at:
https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cache-modes

Comment: Update added. Multiple environments means separate Ignite clusters working with same data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use per-partition Scan Query, and then compute hashes of every entry in a partition, put them in hashset and compare (or simply add them up, this can give false positives through). Repeat for all partitions.